# Localize my Constructor

Tags: c++

```
class Student
{
private:
    string name;
    int year;
    string semester;
    int AmtClass;
    static string Year[4];

public:
    Student();
    Student(int AmtClass);
    Student(Student &);

    void setName(string name);
    void setYear(int year);
    void setSemester(string semester);
    void setAmtClass(int AmtClass);

    string getName();
    int getYear();
    string getSemester();
    int getAmtClass();

    ~Student()
        {
            if(AmtClass > 0)
                delete [] course;
        }
};

string Student::Year[4] = { "Freshman", "Sophomore", "Junior", "senior" };

Student::Student()
{
name = "";
year = 0;
semester = "";
AmtClass = 0;
}

Student::Student(int amount)
{
AmtClass = amount;

string *pName;
pName = new string[AmtClass];

for(int i = 0; i < AmtClass; i++)
{
    pName[i] = "";
}
}
```

Skipping Accessors and Mutator functions...

```
void readStudentData(Student &);
void printStudentData(Student);

int main()
{
int amount;
cout << "How many courses are you currently taking? ";
cin >> amount;

Student kid;
kid.setAmtClass(amount);

readStudentData(kid);
}

void readStudentData(Student &kid)
{
cin.ignore(10000, '\n');

int amount = kid.getAmtClass();
string name = "";
string semester = "";
int year = 0;

cout << "What is your full name? ";
getline(cin,name);

cout << "\nHow many years have you been in college? ";
cin >> year;

cout << "\nWhat is your current semester? ";
getline(cin,semester);

Student kid1(amount);

cout << "Please enter the name of all your courses." << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    cout << "Course #" << i+1 << " : ";
    getline(cin,pName[i]);
}

}
```

Okay edited this program a bit after realizing my pName is a local variable in the constructor...I am supposed to create a constructor that received an integer parameter corresponding to the number of courses the student is taking.The function dynamically allocates the string array of courses and sets each element to "". And then I am supposed to use this to record the names of the courses the student is taking.

Comment: Can you format your code a little better?

Comment: There is too much noise in the question. You should try to reduce the problem to a smaller test case that exhibits the same problem (which is really unclear in the question). In the process you might discover what the issue really is.

Comment: You can start with the blatant memory leak in the `Student` constructor. The unnecessary for-loop to initialize said leaked `std::string` array can be thrown out while fixing that.

Comment: So to prevent this memory leak should I delete the old memory and then create a new one?

Comment: *What old memory?* And I only format code once. so you're up from here on out. This isn't going to turn into an online debugging session. After fixing what I already described, you may also consider how your semester-read operation doesn't work, since the `year` extraction never consumed the newline from the prior input. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The `Year` array should simply be allocated to the `amount`, and that's it:

```c++
Student::Student(int amount)
    : Year(new std::string[amount]()), AmtClass(amount)
{
}
```

You can also use `std::vector` for this so you do not have to deal with deleting the memory yourself:

```c++
class Student
{
    std::vector<std::string> Year;
    // ...
};

Student::Student(int amount)
    : Year(amount), AmtClass(Year.size())
{
}
```